# Java RegEx - How can I convert every Stringchar into *?

Tags: java, regex, string, input, passwords

I'm creating an input field for passwords in Java. How can I show the text as a password (MyPassword -> **********) using RegEx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = "MyPassword";
str = str.replaceAll(".","*");
```

Comment: Seems funny to use a regex to do that : new String( Arrays.fill( new char[ str.length ], '*'));

Comment: @Snicolas: I know but the question asks for a regex based solution.

Comment: @Snicolas RegEx seems to be more performance-friendly for this case.

Comment: @Snicolas Ok, I did a performance test - your method is about 5 times faster, sorry. :)

Comment: Speed consideration principal matter is not. Worry you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
new String( Arrays.fill( new char[ str.length ], '*'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use swing, use a JPasswordField.

Comment: LWJGL, I create my own GUI components.

Comment: Stéphane: check http://stackoverflow.com/users/693752/snicolas?tab=responses&sort=revisions and please save us from the effort of constantly removing your signature.